# Installing Jenkins on mac o/s Catalina with Java 13 already installed

Tags: jenkins

I installed java 13 prior and now need to install java 8 on my mac. As a newbie can I have 2 java versions on my machine and if yes then how can I make Jenkins installed for which java 8 is must OR is there a way to install Jenkins with java 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple JRE or JDK installed in your machine (standard BE practice) but you can refer only one with your environment variable (usually the latest).

That means that **when you want to run something with java8 you will have to call it using the full path instead of just 'java' **.

I strongly recommend you to use docker and the container to run jenkins , mapping the home folder to a folder in your machine. This will give you full portability and easier upgrades / rollbacks. [link](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/)

PS: welcome to SO !